# Retinex surround function

Tags: image-processing

I am new to c programming and image processing field. I am trying to code single scale retinex using gaussian surround function in spatial domain with PPM image. I am using standard retinex formula as below:

> Ri(x, y) = logIi(x, y) - log[F(x, y)*Ii(x, y)]

wher sub-index i represents ith spectral band and c is the constant.Ri (x, y) i is the Retinex output and Ii(x, y)  is the input image distribution in
the i-th spectral band.

I have selected a 3x3 gaussian mask as below:

> F(x,y)=[e^(-2/c^2) e^(-1/c^2) e^(-2/c^2);e^(-1/c^2) 1
>   e^(-1/c^2);e^(-2/c^2) e^(-1/c^2) e^(-2/c^2)]

I have normalized the surround function to 1 before convolution operation. After log operation I have rescaled the values back to 0-255 but contrast is not enhanced in reconstructed image instead the image is dark.  Please find the original and output image attached to the link. As StackOverflow does not support PPM images I have attached PNG versions of the images to the link.I am coding the retinex in c using Dev c++.  Please let me know whether I need to change the surround function or how to proceed with single scale retinex problem.

[image: Original Image]

Hi,

I am new to c programming so please pardon me if program is not as per standards. I have implemented convolution with 3x3 gaussian mask with some logic of my own which is not straightforward. The logic had worked fine when I had done filtering in spatial domain using 3x3 gaussian mask so I have applied same logic to do convolution with 3x3 gaussian mask. Please find the c code which is used to calculate retinex of an color image in spatial domain. I have given suitable comments where ever necessary :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct {
     unsigned char red,green,blue;
} PPMPixel;

typedef struct {
 int x, y;
 PPMPixel *data;
} PPMImage;

#define CREATOR "RPFELGUEIRAS"
#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR 255

static PPMImage *readPPM(const char *filename)
{
   char buff[16];
     PPMImage *img;
    // PPMImage *gaussian;
     FILE *fp;
     int c, rgb_comp_color;
     //open PPM file for reading
     fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
     if (!fp) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
      exit(1);
    }   
     //read image format
  if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) {
       perror(filename);
       exit(1);
  }

//check the image format
if (buff[0] != 'P' || buff[1] != '6') {
   fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image format (must be 'P6')\n");
   exit(1);
}

//alloc memory form image
 img = (PPMImage *)malloc(sizeof(PPMImage));
 if (!img) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
       exit(1);
  }

 //check for comments
 c = getc(fp);
 while (c == '#') {
  while (getc(fp) != '\n') ;
      c = getc(fp);
 }

 ungetc(c, fp);
 //read image size information


 if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &img->x, &img->y) != 2) {          
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image size (error loading '%s')\n", filename);
      exit(1);
 }




 //read rgb component
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &rgb_comp_color) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid rgb component (error loading '%s')\n", filename);
          exit(1);
 }

//check rgb component depth
if (rgb_comp_color!= RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR) {
     fprintf(stderr, "'%s' does not have 8-bits components\n", filename);
     exit(1);
 }

 while (fgetc(fp) != '\n') ;
 //memory allocation for pixel data

 img->data = (PPMPixel*)malloc(img->x * img->y * sizeof(PPMPixel));

 if (!img) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
      exit(1);
}

//read pixel data from file

 if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp) != img->y) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error loading image '%s'\n", filename);
     exit(1);
 }

   fclose(fp);
   return img;
}
void writePPM(const char *filename, PPMImage *img)
{
  FILE *fp;
  //open file for output
  fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
   exit(1);
 }

 //write the header file
 //image format
 fprintf(fp, "P6\n");

 //comments
fprintf(fp, "# Created by %s\n",CREATOR);

//image size
 fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n",img->x,img->y);

 // rgb component depth
 fprintf(fp, "%d\n",RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR);

// pixel data
fwrite(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp);
fclose(fp);
}

void changeColorPPM(int c,PPMImage *img,PPMImage *gaussian)
{
    int i,row,column,z,k=0,l=0;
    float red[9];
    float green[9];
    float blue[9];
    float min1=0,min2=0,min3=0,max1=0,max2=0,max3=0,exp1=0,exp2=0,exp3=0,exp4=0,c1=0,c2=0,c3=0,ct1=0,ct2=0,ct3=0,sum=0;
    float s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6;
    z=img->x;
    float *gaussian_red;
    float *gaussian_green;
    float *gaussian_blue;

    c1=(float)1/(c*c);
    c2=(float)2/(c*c);


    /* Just to avoid memory issues for float assigned maximum memory for float block to handle intermediate data in decimal*/
    gaussian_red =  (float*)malloc(15000000);
    gaussian_green = (float*)malloc(15000000);
    gaussian_blue = (float*)malloc(15000000);



    /* Used taylor series expansion to find  exponenrial values as same were not generated correctly*/
     exp1=1-pow(c1,1)+pow(c1,2)/2-pow(c1,3)/6+pow(c1,4)/24-pow(c1,5)/120+pow(c1,6)/720;
    /* Used taylor series expansion as  exponenrial values were not generated correctly*/
    exp2=1-pow(c2,1)+pow(c2,2)/2-pow(c2,3)/6+pow(c2,4)/24-pow(c2,5)/120+pow(c1,6)/720;

    /* Sum of all the gaussian values are calculated just to normalize the 3x3 gassian mask  to 1 */
    sum=1+4*exp1+4*exp2;

    /* Calculating equivalent pixel value after convolution with 3x3 gaussian mask in spatial domain */
    for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++){
        row=0;
        column=0;
        s1=0,s2=0,s3=0,s4=0,s5=0,s6=0,exp1,exp2;
        row=i/(img->x);
        column=i%(img->x);

        red[9]={0};
        green[9]={0};
        blue[9]={0};

        /* as equivalent gaussian values for a pixel will be gaussian. 
        Storing corresponding pixel value in float array */ 

        gaussian_red[i]=0;
        gaussian_green[i]=0;
        gaussian_blue[i]=0;


        /* When a pixel is multiplied by a 3x3 gaussian mask, the pixel of interest is multiplied by centre of 3x3 
        gaussian mask which is 1 and remaining weights of gaussian masks are multiplied with neighbouring pixels.
        If the  pixel 'i' of interest is present in 1 row , last row, 1st column or last column then all the 3x3
         gaussian weightsmay not find neighbouring pixels in image to get multiplied with. So below we are checking whether
         pixel i is having all the neighbour pixel values to be multiplied with gaussian mask*/

        /* Checking whether Gaussian weight having location (-1,-1)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i-z-1<0 which indicates  1 row and i%(numberofcolumns)=0
           which indicates 1 column. If its 1st row or 1st column then i-z-1 pixel will not be present in image so setting 
           corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if (i-z-1<0 || (i%z)==0)
        { 
            red[0]=0;
            green[0]=0;
            blue[0]=0;

        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (-1,-1) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying gaussian weight 
          with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (-1,-1) with pixel having location (i-z-1) */
        else 
        {
            red[0]=img->data[i-z-1].red*exp2;
            green[0]=img->data[i-z-1].green*exp2;
            blue[0]=img->data[i-z-1].blue*exp2;

        }

        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (0,-1)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i-z<0 which indicates  1 row and when its 1st row 
           i-z pixel will not be not be present in image so setting 
           corresponding product to 0*/ 
        if(i-z<0)
        { 
            red[1]=0;
            green[1]=0;
            blue[1]=0;
        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (0,-1) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (0,-1) with pixel having location (i-z) */
        else 
        {
            red[1]=img->data[i-z].red*exp1;
            green[1]=img->data[i-z].green*exp1;
            blue[1]=img->data[i-z].blue*exp1; 

        }
        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (1,-1)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i-z11<0 which indicates  1 row and i%(numberofcolumns-1)=0
           which indicates last column. If its 1st row or last column then i-z+1 pixel will not be present in image so 
           setting corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if (i-z+1<0|| i%(z-1)==0)
        { 
            red[2]=0;
            green[2]=0;
            blue[2]=0;
        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (1,-1) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (1,-1) with pixel having location (i-z+1) */
        else 
        {
            red[2]=img->data[i-z+1].red*exp2;
            green[2]=img->data[i-z+1].green*exp2;
            blue[2]=img->data[i-z+1].blue*exp2;


        }
        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (-1,0)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i%z=0 which indicates  1 column a. If its 1st column 
           then i-z pixel will not be present in image so setting corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if (i%(z)==0)
        { 
            red[3]=0;
            green[3]=0;
            blue[3]=0;
        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (-1,0) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (-1,0) with pixel having location (i-1) */
        else 
        {
            red[3]=img->data[i-1].red*exp1;
            green[3]=img->data[i-1].green*exp1;
            blue[3]=img->data[i-1].blue*exp1;

        } 
        /* This is the particular pixel of interest so we are multiplying with centre of gaussian mask having weight 1 */ 

            red[4]=(float)img->data[i].red;
            green[4]=(float)img->data[i].green;
            blue[4]=(float)img->data[i].blue;

        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (1,0)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i%(z-1)<0 which indicates last column.
            If its 1st row or last column then i+1 pixel will not be present in image so setting 
           corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if (i!=0 && i%(z-1)==0)
        { 
            red[5]=0;
            green[5]=0;
            blue[5]=0;
        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (1,0) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (1,0) with pixel having location (i+1) */
        else 
        {
            red[5]=img->data[i+1].red*exp1;
            green[5]=img->data[i+1].green*exp1;
            blue[5]=img->data[i+1].blue*exp1;    
        }
        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (-1,1)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i+z-1>(Totalnumberofpixels) which indicates  last row and i%(numberofcolumns-1)=0
           which indicates last column. If its last row or 1st column then i+z-1 pixel will not be present in image so 
           setting corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if ((i+z-1>img->x*img->y)|| i%z==0)
        { 
            red[6]=0;
            green[6]=0;
            blue[6]=0;
        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (-1,1) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (-1,1) with pixel having location (i+z-1) */
        else 
        {
            red[6]=img->data[i+z-1].red*exp2;
            green[6]=img->data[i+z-1].green*exp2;
            blue[6]=img->data[i+z-1].blue*exp2; 
        }
        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (0,1)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i+z>(Totalnumberofpixels) which indicates last row. 
           If its last row then i+z pixel will not be present in image so setting 
           corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if ((i+z)>img->x*img->y)
        { 
            red[7]=0;
            green[7]=0;
            blue[7]=0;
         }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (0,1) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (0,1) with pixel having location (i+z) */
        else
        {
            red[7]=img->data[i+z].red*exp1;
            green[7]=img->data[i+z].green*exp1;
            blue[7]=img->data[i+z].blue*exp1;
        }
        /* Checking whether Gaussian mask having location (1,1)  is fitting with any pixel in image otherwise 
           setting corresponding value to 0. We are checking if i+z+1>(Totalnumberofpixels) which indicates last row. 
           and i%(numberofcolumns-1)=0 whic =h indicates last row.If its last row and last column
           then i+z+1 pixel will not be present in image so setting corresponding product to 0. */ 
        if ((i+z+1>img->x*img->y|| i%(z-1)==0) && i!=0)
        { 
            red[8]=0;
            green[8]=0;
            blue[8]=0;
        }
        /*If Gaussian mask having location (1,1) fits any pixel value in image then multiplying 
         same with that pixel value. Here 'z' is the total number of column. we are multiplying gaussian mask
         (1,1) with pixel having location (i+z+1) */
        else 
        {
            red[8]=img->data[i+z+1].red*exp2;
            green[8]=img->data[i+z+1].green*exp2;
            blue[8]=img->data[i+z+1].blue*exp2;             
        }

        // Normalising sum of gaussian values of red channel by dividing with sum of  all weights of gaussian mask
        s1=(red[0]+red[1]+red[2]+red[3]+red[4]+red[5]+red[6]+red[7]+red[8])/sum;
        // Normalising sum of gaussian values of green channel  by dividing with sum of  all weights of gaussian mask
        s2=(green[0]+green[1]+green[2]+green[3]+green[4]+green[5]+green[6]+green[7]+green[8])/sum;
        // Normalising sum of gaussian values of blue channel  by dividing with sum of  all weights of gaussian mask
        s3=(blue[0]+blue[1]+blue[2]+blue[3]+blue[4]+blue[5]+blue[6]+blue[7]+blue[8])/sum;

        gaussian_red[i]=(float)s1;
        gaussian_green[i]=(float)s2;
        gaussian_blue[i]=(float)s3;

        //Applying retinex function
        s4=log(img->data[i].red+1)-log(s1+1);
        s5=log(img->data[i].green)-log(s2+1);
        s6=log(img->data[i].blue)-log(s3+1);

        gaussian_red[i]=(float)s4;
        gaussian_green[i]=(float)s5;
        gaussian_blue[i]=(float)s6;

    }


        max1=0;
        max2=0;
        max3=0;
                    /* FInding maximum  values for red,green and blue channels */
        for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++)
        {   

            if(gaussian_red[i]>max1)
            {
                max1=gaussian_red[i];
            }
                if(gaussian_green[i]>max2)
            {
                max2=gaussian_green[i];
            }
                if(gaussian_blue[i]>max3)
            {
                    max3=gaussian_blue[i];
            }

        }



        min1=0;
        min2=0;
        min3=0;
        /* Calculating minimum values for all 3 channels after applying retinex formula*/
        for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++)
        {   

            if(gaussian_red[i]<min1)
            {
                min1=gaussian_red[i];                   
            }
            if(gaussian_green[i]<min2)
            {
                min2=gaussian_green[i];                         
            }
            if(gaussian_blue[i]<min3)
            {
                min3=gaussian_blue[i];
            }

        }

        /*Adding minimum values from above step to all pixel value. This is done as part of rescaling
         the values from decimal back to 0-255*/
        for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++)
        {           
            gaussian_red[i]=gaussian_red[i]-min1;
            gaussian_green[i]=gaussian_green[i]-min2;               
            gaussian_blue[i]=gaussian_blue[i]-min3;

        }



        printf("the maximum values are %f,%f,%f\n",max1,max2,max3); 
        /* Rescaling decimal data back to 0-255 for all three channels*/
        for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++)
        {   
            printf("the values before are %d,%d,%d\n",img->data[i].red,img->data[i].green,img->data[i].blue);
            img->data[i].red=(gaussian_red[i]*255/(max1-min1));
            img->data[i].green=(gaussian_green[i]*255/(max2-min2));     
            img->data[i].blue=(gaussian_blue[i]*255/(max3-min3));
            printf("the values after are %d,%d,%d\n",img->data[i].red,img->data[i].green,img->data[i].blue);
         }


 }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int c;  
   c=atoi(argv[3]);
   PPMImage *image; 
   image = readPPM(argv[1]);   
   changeColorPPM(c,image,image); 
    writePPM(argv[2],image);

    }
```

Comment: there is too little here: your formulas may be right but the implementation suffers : show the code

Answer (score 0):

As far as image processing your solution seems correct.

The scaling at the end seems to be in trouble - however you will still struggle to get a viewable result.

The multiple min/max seems wrong and can be reduced to one:

```
find min/max for each channel
for(each pixel) newvalue=255*(oldvalue-min)/(max-min)
```

or

```
 for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++) {
   img->data[i].red=255*(gaussian_red[i]-min1)/(max1-min1);
   img->data[i].green=255*(gaussian_green[i]-min2)/(max2-min2);     
   img->data[i].blue=255*(gaussian_blue[i]-min3)/(max3-min3);
 }
```

Comment: As per your comments I have done code changes but still reconstructed image is reddish. In earlier code I had not added retinex logic i.e. log(img->data[i].red+1)-log(s1+1) , now I have updated the correct code with changes as mentioned by you earlier. Requesting you to please check the code and let me know if any changes are required.